# Installation Fail due to admin rights in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I m trying to install Sql server 2008 R2 with Window 7 Ultimate 64 bit . But during installation in setup support rules checking its not pass the Rule "Setup administrator " instalation fail with the message "The account running SQL Server Setup does not have administator rights on the computer. To continue, use an account with administrator rights." ... I give my account to all admin priv![enter image description here][1]ilege still I repeatedly found this error .Plz help

Comment: Are you *sure* the account you're logged in with is a computer Administrator account? Are you connected to Active Directly or anything else that might mess with your security configurations.

Comment: Yes . M sure . I right click on setup and run it with administartor account .

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error today, after tryiing everything described I used process monitor and realized that I might have a missing file sqlsccn.dll under x64 folder. Apparently if this file is missing you might see the exact same behavior. So in case the above fails, check your media

thanks